# simple class as data container: Howto?

Tags: python

I want a class with static attributes that can be stored using one or more get methods from outside and the stored values can be retrieved using one or more get methods

```
class contract_data:
    contract_header = dict()
    contract_item   = dict()
    contract_schedule = dict()
#    @staticmethod
    def put_header(line:list,findex:dict):
        contract_header[line[findex['VBELN_VA']]] = {'KNKLI':[line[findex['KNKLI']]],
                                                     'VTWEG':[line[findex['VTWEG']]],
                                                     'SPART':[line[findex['SPART']]],
                                                     'VKBUR':[line[findex['VKBUR']]],
                                                     'VKGRP':[line[findex['VKGRP']]],
                                                     'BSTKD':[line[findex['BSTKD']]]
                                                     }
    def get_header(keyval:str)->dict:
        return contract_header[keyval]
#     @staticmethod
    def put_item(line: list, findex: dict):
        return
    @staticmethod
    def put_schedule(line: list, findex: dict):
        return
```

I expected that calling `contract_data.put_header(line,findex)` I could store values in `contract_data` attribute `contract_header`. But it fails with runtime error
in `put_header`:

```
contract_header[line[findex['VBELN_VA']]] = {'KNKLI':[line[findex['KNKLI']]],

NameError: name 'contract_header' is not defined. Did you mean: 'contract_data'?
```

I played around with  `@staticmethod` and `.self` or `self.` with no success.
I expect the class attributes, the dictionaries can be used within the class but not outside.

Answer (score 0):

Your dicts are not global variables; they're class attributes, and as such need to be accessed from the class. That means your static methods need to be defined as class methods.

```
class contract_data:
    contract_header = dict()
    contract_item   = dict()
    contract_schedule = dict()

    @classmethod
    def put_header(cls, line: list, findex: dict):

        cls.contract_header[line[findex['VBELN_VA']]] = {
            k: [line[findex[k]]]
            for k in ['KNKLI', 'VTWEB', 'SPART', 'VKBUR', 'VKGRP', 'BSTKD']}

    @classmethod
    def get_header(cls, keyval: str)->dict:
        return cls.contract_header[keyval]

    ...
```